# Diagonalizable upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

It is true that if an upper triangular matrix $A$ with complex entries has distinct elements on the diagonal, then $A$ is diagonalizable. However, I don't think the converse is true. Is there a complete characterization of all diagonalizable upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Yes, this is true. In case there are eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than $1$, both cases can occur: $A$ can be be diagonalizable or not diagonalizable.

Comment: "Diagonalisable upper-triangular matrices" sounds like a pretty solid characterisation to me :P I don't know of any way to characterise them except by characterising diagonalisability separately (e.g. eigenvectors span, etc.)

Comment: A heuristic idea of why we shouldn't expect a good result: by Schur's decomposition, every complex square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix. If in addition to the eigenvalues we could read the geometric multiplicities from the entries of a triangular matrix, by these days we'd already have a well-known algorithm to look for general diagonalizability from Schur's decomposition.

Answer (score 9):

Every upper triangular matrix with distinct elements on the diagonal is diagonalizable, because
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\prod_{i=1}^n (a_{ii}-\lambda)$$
with $a_{ii}\neq a_{jj}$ for $i\neq j$, so every eigenvalue has multiplicity $1$.
The converse is not true. Take $A=I$. Then $A$ is diagonalized, but not with distinct values on the diagonal.