# check the validity of the statement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, diagonalization

Let $A$ ne an $n\times n $ upper triangular matrix with complex enries.I have to check the validity of the statement

> If $A\neq I$ and if $a_{ii}=1$ $\forall i, 1\le i\le n$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable.

I wanted to know whether my proof(given below) is correct or not?Please provide the correct proof...
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagonalizability of $A \in M_{n}(\Bbb{R})$ (Upper traingular matrix) with all diagonal entries 1 and $A \neq I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574046/diagonalizability-of-a-in-m-n-bbbr-upper-traingular-matrix-with-all-d)

Comment: @Jan:I've alreday read it.But I want to know what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Please [do not use image for the essential part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that there is no pivot volumn is false.

Consider an explicit example: $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

then we have $A-I=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

The second column is a pivot column.

In general, we know that for your setting, we are going to have positive number of pivot columns.

Comment: :What is the Geometric multiplicity then?What is the number of free variables?

Comment: :I think its Geometric multiplicity is 2,because it has 2 free variables(there are two columns without pivots $C_1$ and $C_n$)?

Comment: For my particular matrix, let's solve for $(A-I)x=0$,  the only condition is $x_2=0$, $x_1$ is the free variable here, it can take any value, $x_2$ must take value $0$, it is not a free variable. The leading non-zero element of $A-I$ appears as the second column, it is not a free variable, There is no leading non-zero eleemnt in the first column, it is a free variable. The geometric multiplicity is equal to $1$ in my example.